# Kubernetes: Outside endpoint as service

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, we could use services to expose internal deployments as service-endpoints. But, how to map outside domain name into Kubernetes service to simply call the internal service before the external service?

Comment: Are you trying to expose an internal service to outside, or trying to expose an external name as an internal service?

Comment: I need to consume outside service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services of type ExternalName map a Service to a DNS name, not to a typical selector such as my-service or cassandra. You specify these Services with the spec.externalName parameter.
This Service definition, for example, maps the `my-service` Service in the prod namespace to `my.database.example.com`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Note: ExternalName accepts an IPv4 address string, but as a DNS names comprised of digits, not as an IP address. ExternalNames that resemble IPv4 addresses are not resolved by CoreDNS or ingress-nginx because ExternalName is intended to specify a canonical DNS name. To hardcode an IP address, consider using headless Services.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services

Comment: what is the different between EndPoint and ExternalName?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose an external name as a Kubernetes service so the pods within the cluster can access that internal service to talk to the outside name:

The doc is:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Something like below will work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```